# Is an Iranian independent contractor working remotely for a Cypriotic company required to report income to Cyprus?

Tags: tax-law, iran, cyprus

Is an Iranian citizen working remotely from Iran as an independent contractor for a Cypriotic company required to report income to Cyprus? Are the received compensations taxable in Cyprus?

Comment: By "Iranian independent contractor", do you mean an individual working in Iran, regardless of their citizenship?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user6726 I would be an Iranian citizen working from Iran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [treaty between Cyprus and Iran](http://mof.gov.cy/assets/modules/wnp/articles/201610/45/editor/iran_2015_08_04_1st_en.pdf) which avoids double taxation. By your description, you are exclusively a resident of Iran, meaning that you are subject to Iranian tax law (article 4), also see article 14. You do not gain Cypriot tax liability because of you have a contract with a Cypriot firm.